# The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format when updating MySql.Data 8.0.26

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql.data

I have a dependency on MySql.Data in my C# netcoreapp2.1 test project which I use to query for test data from a database, this works fine with v8.0.25, but if I upgrade to v.8.0.26 I get the following error (without any other code changes).

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Dev.Tests.Foo' threw an exception.
----> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : SSL Connection error.
----> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.)
----> System.IO.IOException : The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

I've tried looking in the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-26.html) for anything that might have changed in this release to do this but can't see anything obvious (to me anyway).

Has anyone else had this issue upgrading MySql.Data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your host doesn't support SSL you can use SSL Mode options, None or Required.

Connection string must be contain this option like;

```
"..OTHER_OPTIONS..;SSL Mode=None"
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839479/c-sharp-mysql-ssl-connection-error-when-trying-to-use-conn-open/68839784#68839784

Comment: Ah thank you, so that's something that's been brought in since the last version?

Comment: If its a duplicate then please flag it as such, dont answer the same question twice please

Comment: The other one should be marked to come here - this question was asked much more concisely, even without the code sample.  Hmm. That's what concisely means I suppose..